# why there is a circle of light surrounding Sun and Moon?

Tags: light

One day when I was playing basketball I saw a circle around the bright Sun. It is a perfect circle with a radius of about 20-30 km.

Why does this circle of light form? I have seen the same also around the moon. But this does not happen every day. Why ?

Comment: Radius of 20 - 30 km? What do you base that on?

Comment: I just imagine.

Answer (score 2):

Most probable you have been experiencing a weather phenomena: Ice crystals in the sky reflect or bend the light to form a [halo](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/22%C2%B0_halo).

So, this depends on the temperatures and moisture content of the atmosphere and cannot be seen every day.